# Error when trying to compile (after everything else has been done) GAMESS on Windows/WSL

Tags: software-assistance, gamess, windows-operating-system, webmo

I requested a copy of GAMESS, downloaded it, installed ATLAS because the config file said "please download a math library" and built ATLAS. I then tried to compile it using the compall file. Got "command not found" compilation errors(no pics as I tried taking a pic of the screen and it was over 2MB)- no matter how many times do I re-configure GAMESS and select various compilers. How do I fix this problem? My device is a Surface, using Windows/WSL.

Comment: Rather than an image, you should include the error text as a code block. This will help us determine what command is not found.

Comment: Did you install a compiler in the system, beforehand?

Comment: Yes, if following the prompt installs it

Comment: Why do you need to compile GAMESS on WSL? It's binaries are already available for Windows natively? You can get pre-compiled windows binaries by registering: https://www.msg.chem.iastate.edu/GAMESS/download/register/

Comment: I need it for WebMO.

Comment: I have never used webmo sorry. Are you trying to compile gamess to keep it on a server and make it available via webmo? Also feel free to answer your own question if you have managed to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I installed GFortran 9.4 and re-ran the `compall` file. The compilation succeeded but the `gamess.00.x` file was missing and GAMESS couldn't run. Then I re-configured it ***without*** turning on the `XMVB` option: This was now successful.